# permission errors while using pysftp and paramiko

Tags: python, python-3.7, paramiko, pysftp

I have a use case to transfer file over sftp, planning to use paramiko or pysftp modules of python3.7 and having troubles with one of the destinations/targets. File transfer works fine when winSCP is used. Any suggestions to resolve this issue or what could be the specific reason for this target.

**Approach#1: using paramiko and open_sftp**

```
import paramiko
import os
ssh_client =paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.load_system_host_keys()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect(hostname='abc.com', username='username', password='pwd')
sftp_client=ssh_client.open_sftp()

print(sftp_client.stat(path='/receive/file))
sftp_client.file("createfile","w+")
print(sftp_client.listdir(path='/receive/file'))
```

**Approach#1 - Error**

```
drwxrwxrwx   1 0        0               0 12 Mar 13:18 ?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sftp_linux.py", line 32, in <module>
    sftp_client.file("createfile","w+")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 372, in open
    t, msg = self._request(CMD_OPEN, filename, imode, attrblock)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 813, in _request
    return self._read_response(num)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 865, in _read_response
    self._convert_status(msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 896, in _convert_status
    raise IOError(errno.EACCES, text)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Can not create createfile
```

**Approach#2: using pysftp**

```
import os
import sys
import pysftp
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None
sftp_client = pysftp.Connection(host='abc.com', username='username', password='pwd', cnopts=cnopts,port=22)
print(sftp_client)
sftp_client.chdir ('/receive/file')
print(sftp_client.pwd)
print(sftp_client.listdir())
sftp_client.put('testingfile',preserve_mtime=True)
sftp_client.close()
```

**Approach#2: using pysftp - error**

```
[]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sftp_linux.py", line 15, in <module>
    sftp_client.put('testingfile',preserve_mtime=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pysftp/__init__.py", line 364, in put
    confirm=confirm)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 759, in put
    return self.putfo(fl, remotepath, file_size, callback, confirm)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 720, in putfo
    s = self.stat(remotepath)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 493, in stat
    t, msg = self._request(CMD_STAT, path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 813, in _request
    return self._read_response(num)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 865, in _read_response
    self._convert_status(msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 894, in _convert_status
    raise IOError(errno.ENOENT, text)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] /receive/file/testingfile
```

Comment: Show us a log file of a successful upload or the same file using WinSCP. + What it the purpose of the `/receive/file`?